# In JFreeChart, how to change text align of category labels in a horizontal bar chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm working in a chart that has the following presentation:

[image]

¿How do I make the category labels left aligned or justified? Actually they look centered but that is not what I require.

The code that I'm using is the following:

```
JFreeChart chart = getChart();
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setDrawBarOutline(true);

CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(5);

CategoryLabelPositions p = domainAxis.getCategoryLabelPositions();

CategoryLabelPosition left = new CategoryLabelPosition(
    RectangleAnchor.LEFT, TextBlockAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, 
    TextAnchor.CENTER_LEFT, 0.0,
    CategoryLabelWidthType.RANGE, 0.70f //Assign 70% of space for category labels
);

domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions
        .replaceLeftPosition(p, left));

NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke(1);
plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.black);
plot.setDomainGridlineStroke(stroke);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.black);
plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(stroke);

CategoryDataset cd = plot.getDataset();

setBarColors(renderer, plot, cd);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category labels are instances of `org.jfree.text.TextBlock`, which does have a `setLineAlignment(HorizontalAlignment alignment)` method, but I'm not seeing a way to get to them through the CategoryPlot or CategoryAxis APIs (there are a ton of methods and casts, so I can't tell you definitively such a method doesn't exist, just that I haven't found one).  Overriding the `createLabel` method in `CategoryAxis` to set the alignment works, though.

(before your code to get the domain axis):

```
plot.setDomainAxis(new CategoryAxis() {
    @Override
    protected TextBlock createLabel(Comparable category, float width, RectangleEdge edge, Graphics2D g2) {
        TextBlock label = TextUtilities.createTextBlock(category.toString(), getTickLabelFont(category), getTickLabelPaint(category), width, this.getMaximumCategoryLabelLines(), new G2TextMeasurer(g2));
        label.setLineAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
        return label;
    }
});
```

You may want to post a request to the [JFreeChart Forums](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=3) or [JFreeChart Feature Requests](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/feature-requests/) as David Gilbert would be the best person to answer this definitively.

Comment: The label text is aligned to the left, which is correct. Now I have to workaround the left sides alignment. Thanks a lot Zebby.

Comment: The left sides alignment is done with CategoryLabelPositions, which is already used in above code.